# oracle case when then ora-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected char got number

Tags: oracle

I tried to do some formula calculation as below

```
( CASE
WHEN X <= 0.04 THEN X
WHEN X > 0.04 AND X <= 0.05 THEN TO_CHAR(X-0.010, '9,999,999.99')
WHEN X > 0.05 AND X <= 0.07 THEN TO_CHAR(X-0.020, '9,999,999.99')
WHEN X > 0.07 AND X <= 0.120 THEN TO_CHAR(X-0.030, '9,999,999.99')
WHEN X > 0.12 AND X <= 0.150 THEN TO_CHAR(X-0.040, '9,999,999.99')
ELSE TO_CHAR(X -0.05, '9,999,999.99') 
END
)
```

Using the value

```
0.45
-0.01
```

when I use the query above, I will below result after going thru the formula

```
.35
-0.01
```

it changes 0.35 to char and the leading zero is missing.
is there a way I can retain the 0. ? If i do not change character I will get expect char got number.

Comment: Why didn't you used `TO_CHAR(X -0.05, '9,999,999.99')` in the else part?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. yes it shall be there

Comment: I tried 9d999. It generated trailing zero which I cannot have it

Answer (score 0):

In the second line you return a number datatype

```
WHEN X <= 0.04 THEN X
```

while on the other lines you return a char datatype

```
WHEN X > 0.04 AND X <= 0.05 THEN TO_CHAR(X-0.010, '9,999,999.99')
```

You must use the same datatype every time. So if you change your second line to

```
WHEN X <= 0.04 THEN to_char(X, '9,999,999.99')
```

it should work.

If you want a leading zero you can use this format string:

```
to_char(X, '9,999,990.99')
```

A 9 means omitting trailing zeros, while a 0 means return leading zeros. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210